# Exception when disabling a whole Form in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have this form in Wicket, that has to be disabled when an user with a certain Role is logged in.

In the onConfigure() method I check the Role, and if it is the one that is not allowed to change anything I disable the Form:

```
getForm().setEnabled(!isSponsor());
```

But then, I get this error:

```
org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: file:/bla/bla/bla/Panel.html: Component [printButton] (path = [1:work:child:bla:7:bla:fieldContainer:field:modal:content:form:Panel:printButton]) must be applied to a tag of type [button,input,a], not:  '<span wicket:id="printButton" id="printButtonb3">' (line 0, column 0)
    at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.util.Components.createMarkupException(Components.java:96) ~[wicket-bootstrap-core-0.8.4.jar:?]
    at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.util.Components.assertTag(Components.java:80) ~[wicket-bootstrap-core-0.8.4.jar:?]
    at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.util.Components.assertTag(Components.java:65) ~[wicket-bootstrap-core-0.8.4.jar:?]
    at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.markup.html.bootstrap.button.ButtonBehavior.onComponentTag(ButtonBehavior.java:134) ~[wicket-bootstrap-core-0.8.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponentTag(Component.java:3970) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2540) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1493) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2379) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1390) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1529) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:689) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:76) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2549) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1493) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2379) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1390) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1529) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1484) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:71) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2549) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1493) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2379) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1390) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1529) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1484) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:71) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2549) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1493) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2379) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1390) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1529) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1484) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onComponentTagBody(Form.java:1683) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:71) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2549) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1493) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2379) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1390) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1529) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:689) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:76) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2549) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1493) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2379) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1390) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1529) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:689) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:76) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2549) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1493) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2379) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2307) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.XmlAjaxResponse.writeComponent(XmlAjaxResponse.java:127) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractAjaxResponse.writeComponents(AbstractAjaxResponse.java:213) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractAjaxResponse.writeTo(AbstractAjaxResponse.java:145) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestHandler.respond(AjaxRequestHandler.java:363) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:861) ~[wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) ~[wicket-request-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:97) ~[wicket-request-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261) [wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218) [wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289) [wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259) [wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201) [wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137) [wicket-core-6.9.0.jar:6.9.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) [servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:?]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1148) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180) [spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1139) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66) [log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar:2.0-beta9]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1139) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:378) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:865) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228) [jetty-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520) [jetty-util-6.1.15.jar:6.1.15]
2014-10-27 12:22:10,627 WARN  [6748295@qtp-24450551-0 RequestCycleExtra] ********************************
2014-10-27 12:22:10,627 ERROR [6748295@qtp-24450551-0 DefaultExceptionMapper] Unexpected error occurred
```

But in the markup I have this:

```
<a wicket:id="printButton">Print View</a>
```

And in the java file printButton is an `BootstrapAjaxLink`.

If I erase the line that disables the Form, then is everything OK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about `BootstrapAjaxLink`, if you [look](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.agilecoders.wicket/wicket-bootstrap-core/0.8.1/de/agilecoders/wicket/markup/html/bootstrap/button/BootstrapAjaxLink.java?av=f#47) at it's source code, then u'll see, that it adds `ButtonBehavior`, which has overriden `onComponentTag` method ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.agilecoders.wicket/wicket-bootstrap-core/0.8.1/de/agilecoders/wicket/markup/html/bootstrap/button/ButtonBehavior.java#132)) with following check:

```
Components.assertTag(component, tag, "a", "button", "input");
```

This code throws an error, because disabled link has tag `span`, as you already mentioned.

Do not know, why it was implemented like this, and yes, you can override `disableLink` method, but better way is to use `BootstrapAjaxButton` and `<input type="submit" value="ok"/>` markup.

It only adds `disabled="disabled"` tag to disabled button's markup, and error won't be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found that BootrstrapAjaxLink extends AjaxLink that has the following method:

```
@Override
    protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag)
    {
        super.onComponentTag(tag);

        if (isLinkEnabled())
        {
            // disable any href attr in markup
            if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("a") || tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link") ||
                tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("area"))
            {
                tag.put("href", "#");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            disableLink(tag);
        }

    }
```

and disableLink goes as follows:

```
/**
     * Alters the tag so that the link renders as disabled.
     * 
     * This method is meant to be called from {@link #onComponentTag(ComponentTag)} method of the
     * derived class.
     * 
     * @param tag
     */
    protected void disableLink(final ComponentTag tag)
    {
        // if the tag is an anchor proper
        if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("a") || tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link") ||
            tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("area"))
        {
            // Change anchor link to span tag
            tag.setName("span");

            // Remove any href from the old link
            tag.remove("href");

            tag.remove("onclick");
        }
        // if the tag is a button or input
        else if ("button".equalsIgnoreCase(tag.getName()) ||
            "input".equalsIgnoreCase(tag.getName()))
        {
            tag.put("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
```

That was the problem... so if I override this, it works... but why would a link be changed to span if wicket complains about it later??

Comment: Historically Wicket's link changed their markup to span when disabled, this will change in Wicket 7 (see WICKET-4904). Note that it is wicket-bootstrap which complains about the tag name.